# Can't login after forced shutdown

Tags: login, shutdown, lightdm

I am on ubuntu 12.04 and forced a shutdown (hardware switch). Now I can't login anymore. In particular, after entering my password I get sent back to the login screen. The error message is to fast for me to read. I am, however, able to login into the Guest account through the usual login screen, and able to login into my own account on tty1 after pressing `Ctrl+Alt+F1`. What should I try to get back into my own account via the login screen and get back to a working desktop?

Update: I can login with gdm, but not with the (default) lightdm. So the forced shutdown seems to have broken lightdm. The question now is, how do I fix a broken lightdm?

Comment: Press Ctl+Atl+F1 from login screen. It will open a terminal. Now try to login using your user name and password. Let us know what happen.

Comment: @shantanu I can login. I had also tried `sudo stop gdm`, but it just tells me `stop: Unknown instance:`.

Comment: it's not gdm anymore. It's `lightdm`. Try `sudo stop lightdm` and `sudo start lightdm`

Comment: @Web-E I see. stopping and restarting lightdm still doesn't get me past the login screen in lightdm, but I am able to login with gdm, after starting it.

Comment: try to reinstall lightdm (sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm) after that restart lightdm (sudo service lightdm restart)

Comment: @shantanu I "completely remove"d lightdm via synaptic, reinstalled and set back as default display manager with no change...

Comment: ok.. Another test.. Load login page(lightdm), try to login once using your user name and password(will fail). Now (ctl+alt+F1) go to terminal mode. Login using your user name and password. Now read  /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log  (cat  /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log). Check out the error messages  and also (dmesg -c )

Comment: @shantanu The log contains nothing suspicious as far as I can tell. Last few lines: `[+8.24s] DEBUG: Started session 1985 with service 'lightdm', username 'user'
[+8.25s] DEBUG: Session 1985 got 1 message(s) from PAM
[+8.25s] DEBUG: Prompt greeter with 1 message(s)
` What is PAM?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are able to login with gdm try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm` and select gdm as default display manager.

Comment: As a workaround. Thanks, that should work. Is there no hope to understand what went wrong with lightdm?

Comment: some configuration got changed/corrupted. You can also try to reconfigure lightdm. This kind of problem generally happens when you upgrade from one ubuntu version to another and you have different display manager.

Comment: I completely removed and reinstalled lightdm with no change. Could it still be a configuration issue?

Comment: removing one component doesn't always remove configs. And what I know lightdm also depends upon `unity-greeter`. That may also got corrupted. [A link for reference](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1876829). Hopefully we will receive some better answer on this topic.

Comment: I also removed and reinstalled unity-greeter. I'll try some of the suggestions in your reference.